# How to .set a .globl symbol in GAS?

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have a function `original_fun` defined in one file (`original_fun.c`), and I need to refer to it as `global_alias` in file `use_alias.c`. I tried the following:

```
#  set_alias.s
.globl global_alias
.set global_alias, original_fun

// original_fun.c
#include <stdio.h>
void original_fun(int x) 
{
  printf("original_fun(%d)\n", x);
}

// use_alias.c
extern void global_alias(int x);
int main()
{
  global_alias(42);
  return 0;
}
```

But the symbol `global_alias` is not exported:

```
$ as set_alias.s -o set_alias.o
$ clang original_fun.c -c -o original_fun.o
$ clang use_alias.c -c -o use_alias.o
$ clang set_alias.o original_fun.o use_alias.o -o result
use_alias.o: In function `main':
use_alias.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `global_alias'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And `objdump` reports:

```
$ objdump -rt set_alias.o
set_alias.o:     file format elf32-i386
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000         *UND*  00000000 original_fun
```

(The motivating example is that `original_fun` is a mangled C++ name, and I would like to export it under a cleaner name, so that it can be easily used from assembler.)

The GAS manual (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Set.html) states the following:

> If you .set a global symbol, the value stored in the object file is the last value stored into it.

This might be related to my problem, but I am not sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: My answer is use `extern "C"` or rethink your design. Why do you need to call the function from assembly? Would not using overloading solve the issue? Is this the only overload that would be declared `extern "C"`? Could you use an entry function that is declared `extern "C"`? If the function requires data that you are generating using assembly, why is this not in a self-contained assembly procedure that can be called from `original_fun` instead of the other way around like you're trying to do?

Comment: I need to call the functions (and refer to the constants) from assembly because the assembler is output from a compiler and C++ is the language of the runtime library. Names of functions are mangled even if there is no overload, as the compiler can never be sure there won't be any overload later or in another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic reason why what you're trying to do doesn't work is because `gas` doesn't know the "value" of `original_fun`, as it is an external symbol. When assembling references to `original_fun`, it can only emit relocation directives, which is different from emitting the actual value of it.

What `.set` then does instead is to locally make `global_alias` a kind-of soft alias for `original_fun`, so that it works similar to it. What happens is that every use of `global_alias` in the same file emits a relocation to `original_fun` instead. However, such a mechanic cannot meaningfully be exported as the actual value of `global_alias`, as there is no way to express that idea in ELF. (I don't know if there may some object file-format that is capable of expressing a symbol as being an alias for another symbol, nor do I know if `gas` would support that feature when assembling to that format.)

If you want to make `global_alias` work as you describe it, the `.set` directive would need to be in the same assembly unit as the actual definition of `original_fun`. Technically, if you use GCC, then you could do this with top-level inline assembly:

```
void original_fun(int x) 
{
    printf("original_fun(%d)\n", x);
}
asm(".set global_alias, original_fun");
```

That is clearly not portable to different compilers, however.

Comment: FWIW, while ELF symbol tables are indeed incapable of expressing this kind of “external alias” aka “indirect symbol”, both COFF (thus Windows) and Mach-O (thus macOS) [support them](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2011/07/06/the-sad-state-of-symbol-aliases/), and the `ALIAS` statement in modern versions of MASM aka ML can generate one. (Neither GNU nor LLVM as can.)

Answer (score 1):

> The motivating example is that original_fun is a mangled C++ name, and I would like to export it under a cleaner name, so that it can be easily used from assembler.

Just as an alternative answer, the cleaner solution may be to use `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
    void original_fun(int x) 
    {
        printf("original_fun(%d)\n", x);
    }
}
```

Not only will that require less source files, but AFAIK it is also portable between different C++ compilers.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now, but I would like to avoid having one half of my functions in `extern "C"` and the rest in my `namespace`.

Comment: @honzasp: Why not? Since you're creating top-level symbols for them anyway, what do you have to lose? You can still have them inside the `namespace` block itself, mind you; that is compatible with `extern "C"`.

Comment: If I declare the function in the global namespace (in `extern "C"`), I need to add a prefix to avoid possible name clashes, and I find it ugly to have some names prefixed and some not :) (that's the only reason I need the alias)

Answer (score -1):

> If you .set a global symbol, the value stored in the object file is
>   the last value stored into it.

Reading this I believe it means you are trying to set the alias to a variable which cannot be done, I would try using but I have no way of testing right now!

> const auto& new_fn_name = old_fn_name;

Comment: The reference is just a disguised pointer, so the assembler label `new_fn_name` points to a word memory, where is saved the real address of `old_fn_name`.